# Using both <link> and @import to import the same stylesheet?

Tags: css, import

Is it ever necessary or advisable to use both `<link>` tags and the `@import` command to import a stylesheet? In particular, I'm looking at lines 14-15 of [this page](http://socialmediaclassroom.com/), where it appears both commands are used to import the same stylesheet. Why did the author do this?

*EDIT: For posterity, here's the code in question:*

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='http://socialmediaclassroom.com/index.php?css=site/site_css.v.1223354306' />
<style type='text/css' media='screen'>@import "http://socialmediaclassroom.com/index.php?css=site/site_css.v.1223354306";</style>
```

Comment: I would imagine it might be a mistake, or a misunderstanding on the author's part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's [why](http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/).
I  must say that using the same css is a bit confusing.

Comment: +1, that is almost certainly the reason for this. However, the *real fix* is simply to not use `@import` at all.

Comment: +1 Good find Knu, however as @thirtydot says `@import` seems best just not used.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a single reason to do this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='site_css.v.1223354306' />
<style type='text/css' media='screen'>@import "site_css.v.1223354306";</style>
```

In fact, it seems *retarded*. If there's some obscure reason to do this, someone please tell me :)

The author should get rid of the @import line, because it can cause slow downs in initial page rendering.

See here for why: [don’t use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/), or the [Yahoo recommendations document](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink).